# Multi-stage fully differential bandpass filters

Tags: analog, filter, differential, active-filter

I've recently been doing a bunch of research on analog filtering in preparation for a data acquisition system I'm building. For context, while I'm fairly comfortable with FPGAs and digital/computer engineering, I have far less experience with analog circuitry. I've been reading Analog Filter and Circuit Design Handbook as a reference, as well as a lot of material online.

There's one question I have been unable to find an answer to in all these sources. I would like to use differential signals as far as possible in this circuit, ideally all the way to the ADCs. However, I can't figure out how to construct active, multi-stage filters with fully differential signals. I used Analog Device's filter wizard to spec out a 4th order Chebyshev response comprised of two 2nd order band-pass multiple feedback stages.

Here's the result:
[image: Original circuit]

I'm now trying to 'translate' it to fully differential form. I had two ideas on how to do this. The first is to use the first stage to convert to single-ended, which isn't ideal and also I don't know if it would work. The second idea uses differential signals the whole way through, which would require swapping out the op-amps recommended by the filter wizard for fully differential ones (no big deal). My question is: will either of these work? It seems highly sketchy to get rid of their grounding scheme like that, but I don't know enough about this to decide if it'll work. Any help or direction to other resources would be appreciated. Here's the sketch of my two ideas.

[image: My ideas]

Thanks! 
-Seth

Comment: Do you plan to implement the analog filters on the FPGA? or on a PCB?

Comment: No - your handwritten circuits do not work as desired. For both inputs you need two identical feedback networks. Try a google search for "fully symmetrical filters" (pictures) - and you will find many different circuits.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first proposal deals with common-mode noise only on the first stage. It might be good enough, or might not, depends on your internal grounding.

The second proposal is something like this: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiducc9a/tiducc9a.pdf This is a high-quality front end for a DAQ system, maybe more what you're after.

That said, you will need to re-arrange the MFT filter stages to have feedback on both sides for the second proposal to work. The TI link above shows this.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is a huge help.